# docker : how to install php_mssql extension

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, php-extension

I have a legacy query that uses **@mssql_connect**.

```
$this->_linkIdentifier = @mssql_connect($this->_host, $this->_username, $this->_password);
var_dump($this->_linkIdentifier);die();
```

I created a docker container for php:5.4.42-fpm. i now need to install the  **php_mssql extension**  so that i may use the above query.

```
FROM php:5.4.42-fpm

 # Install the PHP pdo_mysql extention
  RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql \
      docker-php-ext-install mssql
```

This returns an error;

```
ERROR: Service 'php-fpm' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql       && docker-php-ext-install mssql   && docker-php-ext-install pdo_pgsql   && docker-php-ext-configure gd     --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/lib     --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/freetype2 &&     docker-php-ext-install gd' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

**Question:** how do i install mssql extention to my php container.

Comment: Do you must use the version 5.4?

Comment: @Schisme i changed it but it stills gives the same error